# Telerik RadGrid Date column is not formatted to the right format

Tags: formatting, telerik, radgrid

I have the following column in the Telerik Grid:

```
<Columns>   
<telerik:GridDateTimeColumn  DataField="Boardingdate" DataType="System.DateTime" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" SortExpression="Boardingdate" UniqueName="Boardingdate"
    HeaderStyle-Width="10%"/>
</Columns>
```

In my `sql` logic I get this column' date the following way:

```
cast(convert(varchar(30),meredsopen,101) as date)
```

And in the `sql` it's displayed as follows: `2010-10-04`

However, when the Grid renders on the page the date's columns have the values like that:

`8/23/2018 12:00:00 AM` and I cannot sort it as well.

I can convert the date value to string to show `8/23/2018', but in that case, I think, the sorting will be performed on the string and not on the` date` value

How can I fix that?

Comment: Does putting this data I'm a data table and giving that to the grid make a difference (make sure the columns have proper data type set)? If yes, something happens with the SQL query and what it returns (maybe the ssms profiler can help you see what select is generated by the framework when sorting and when not)

Comment: I found the problem why I wasn't able to sort by date . 
I have to use the property `AllowNaturalSort` and set it to `false` on the `MasterTableView`. This way the date is sorted according to its numeric values and not as string